# Unable to read push even tho my data is an array

Tags: reactjs

I was building a for loop to loop into an array that contains multiple objects with keys. The main error comes up saying that "push" isn't defined even tho my exported const is an array.

I have already tried to change the position of the export const variables and changing it to just returning the function which creates the object that piles into the array.

```js
function Data (key, id, age, gender, race, living, income) {
    return {
      key: key,
      id: id,
      age: age,
      gender: gender,
      race: race,
      living: living,
      income: income
    }
}
/* setRandomData {Function}
 * size {param} Int
 * let setOutput
*/
function setRandomData (size) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    let output = (i**3 + 10000);
    let setOutput = output.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    data.push(Data(1+size[i], i, (i + 20), 'NA', 'NA', 'single',setOutput))
  }
}

export const data = [setRandomData(200)]
```

The expected result is the columns will be filled with each parameter from the Data function.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a functional language, which means a function should return something. Please avoid using global variables. You can store the result locally in the function and then return it. Here is the working code:

```
function setRandomData (size) {
  let data = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    let output = (i**3 + 10000);
    let setOutput = output.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    data.push(Data(1+size[i], i, (i + 20), 'NA', 'NA', 'single',setOutput))
  }
  return data;
}
export const data = setRandomData(200)
```